# Can I delete Facebook SKD's Sample apps from my workspace in Android Development

Tags: android, facebook

I just installed Facebook's SDK for Android and I got about 10 new "sample" projects in my workspace along with it. Do I need them? Can I delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need them. They are there just for reference